# ng-repeat doesn't expose array element (angularJS 1.6.6)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

having a problem where ng-repeat doesn't render the array element usable variable.

eg :

```
<li ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4]">{{i}}</li>
```

should render something like:

```
<li>0</li>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
```

But I get:

```
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
```

Comment: Looks like in your real code the `i` is undefined coz `ng-repeat` works

Comment: On the page where I do this I've added exactly the code above, and its behaviour is as described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is working. Maybe something in another place is wrong.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app>
   <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4]">{{i}}</li>
   </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: I know it works have testet it using simple index.html local, but when adding the same code to webpage hosted over webserver, then it doesn't.

even inspected scope using:

    <pre>{{i|json}}</pre>

And list is present, scope is set, and i has correct value, but when accessing i in handlebars then i is empty.

Comment: Found the issue, template engine removed handlebars.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li ng-app ng-repeat="i in [0,1,2,3,4]">{{i}}</li>
```